# Randomly choose matrices $A_{j}B = C_{j}$ with elements between 0 and 1

Tags: computational-geometry, randomized-algorithms, linear-algebra

**Problem**

I have $J$ matrices $C_{j}$, which are $K \times M$.

Elements of each matrix $C_{j}$ are between 0 and 1.

I want to randomly choose $J$ matrices $A_{j}$ and one matrix $B$ such that:

- Elements of all matrices $A_{j}$ and matrix $B$ are between 0 and 1
- $A_{j}B = C_{j}$ for all $j$.
- Dimensions of each matrix $A_{j}$ is $K \times L$
- Dimensions of matrix $B$ is $L \times M$
- $L \lt M \lt\lt J$
- $J$ is ~50,000. $K$, $L$, and $M$ are ~15.

**Attempt**

I thought about the following:

1. Randomly choose a matrix $B$ within bounds.
2. Fix $B$ and find least square solutions $A_{j}$ such that $A_{j}B \approx C_{j}$
3. Replace any element in $A_{j}$ that is not between 0 and 1 by a random value between 0 and 1.
4. Fix $A_{j}$ and find least square solution $B$ such that that $A_{j}B \approx C_{j}$
5. Replace any element in $B$ that is not between 0 and 1 by a random value between 0 and 1.
6. Repeat steps 2 to 6 till converge.

Since $J$ is large, this might take a long time.

**Question**

What is the standard way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: **Please credit the original source of the problem _in the question_.**

Comment: @Apass.Jack Where did you see this problem? What is the "original source"?

Comment: The issue is not about whether I have seen this problem. The  issue is, is this problem created by you? If yes, it is better stated that way.  If not, then it is a general practice that the original copyright owner be credited, unless it is in public domain. Or something like that.